# Data lost due to orientation change when calling start activity for result

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

If I can't make it clear please ask your query don't negative mark it. I'm new user

I made a question answer app in which after answering all question it will go to finish page. Where thre are three buttons which will indicate whether you made right answer or wrong.
You can reanswer your question by clicking on the button 1,2 or 3 which will send the corresponding question no.

**My problem.**

I use  `startActivityForResult` function to go to the finish class from question class and return back with some data then `onActivityResult` function is called and run succesfuly.
But if the orientation of the question class and finish class is not same then  after clicking the question button it does not call the `onActivityResult` function it restart the question class.

This is the code for question class. Where I use `startactivityforresult`:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent (question.this,finish.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                                   intent.putExtra("question1",correct[1]);
  intent.putExtra("question2",correct[2])
  intent.putExtra("question3",correct[3]);
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);


  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          latitude = data.getIntExtra("latitude", 0)
         requstquestion(latitude);

     }}
```

This is the code for finish class:

```
      Intent mintent = getIntent();                 //recive the correct array
    accuracy[1] = mintent.getIntExtra("question1",0);
    accuracy[2] = mintent.getIntExtra("question2",0);
    accuracy[3] = mintent.getIntExtra("question3",0);



     question1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {


            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, 
                    new Intent().putExtra("latitude", 0));
                finish();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    question2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {


            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, 
                    new Intent().putExtra("latitude", 1));
                finish();


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    question3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, 
                    new Intent().putExtra("latitude", 2));
                finish();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Post the whole code? Are these `classes` activities?

Answer (score 1):

In your app's manifest, did you remember to say that your `Question` activity was the parent of your `Finish` activity? Something like this, for example:

```
    <activity android:name=".FinishActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".QuestionActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".QuestionActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Because if you do this then `onActivityResult()` should be called in `QuestionActivity` even if the screen orientation was different when you called `finish()` in `FinishActivity`. I found this by trial and error when facing a similar problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) to your activity for orientation.

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When
>   a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down
>   and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this
>   attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted

```
 <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_android_basics_starter"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Comment: I have different layout for different orientation so i can not do this